# What's the equivalent of `scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner` in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-3

what's the equivalent of `scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner` in dotty?

I checked in the package `dotty.tools.dotc` https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/tree/master/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc
but couldn't find anything.

I tried to use `dotty.tools.dotc.Run` but I got error

> wrap: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: dotty.tools.dotc.Run.main([Ljava.lang.String;)

Comment: Can you use the new annotation? `@main`, you can define it as taking a traditional String array, or define your own argument list.

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/methods-main-methods.html#inner-main

Comment: Nope. That won't work for me. I need it for mainConsole configuration https://github.com/rajcspsg/scala_3_mvn_demo/blob/master/pom.xml#L60. For scala2, default value is scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner. I don't know what to configure in case of scala3

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an equivalent right now. Technically, Scala 3 has not been officially released yet though. Considering the changes to main and the deprecation of App, I wouldn't be surprised if the library is either incompatible or obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scala 3 console is often called the REPL. Its main entrypoint in Scala 3 is `dotty.tools.repl.Main`. You can find it [here](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/master/compiler/src/dotty/tools/repl/Main.scala).

Answer (score 0):

The closest counterpart is `dotty.tools.MainGenericRunner`, although it doesn't provide identical functionality.